# prestashop associated categories in product.tpl

Tags: categories, product, prestashop

I have a product that belongs to two categories "rings" and "collections->waves" (category->subcategory)

I can show **the default category** and it link like this

```
<a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($product->id_category_default,$product->category)}" title="{$product->category}">{$product->category}</a>
```

But I can't show the (non default) **associated categories** anyhow. 
Is there any array with the associated categories in the object $product?

Because I know that all the categories are in the variable $categories (not the subcategories, it could be a problem, cause waves is a subcategory)

Thanks for everything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look to the Product class, it has nice function:

```
/**
 * getProductCategories return an array of categories which this product belongs to
 *
 * @return array of categories
 */
public static function getProductCategories($id_product = '')
{
    $ret = array();
    if ($row = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('
    SELECT `id_category` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product`
    WHERE `id_product` = '.(int)$id_product)
    )
        foreach ($row as $val)
            $ret[] = $val['id_category'];
    return $ret;
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't saw it! 
FYI for other people: In the products.tpl it would be like this to have the array 
`$product->getProductCategories($product->id)`

Comment: I would rather use `Product::getProductCategories($products->id)` considering the function is static